# Reading strings in file upon split()

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, split

Content of the file with name sketch1.txt

```
Man: Is this the right room for an argument?
Other Man: I've told you once.
Man: No you haven't!
Other Man: Yes I have.
Man: When?
Other Man: Just now.
Man: No you didn't!
```

**Code:**

```
try:
     def read_file( ):
          data = open('C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\eBook\\PythonData\\sketch1.txt', 'r')
     print ("---- read all---")
     for read_lines in data:
          try:
               if read_lines.find(':') != -1:
                    (role, line_said) = read_lines.split(":", 1)
                    print(role +' says ' +line_said)
               else:
                    print(read_lines)
          except:
               pass

except:
     print("data file is missing")
```

**Result:**
Worked once, but not every time i ran

```
---- read all---
Man says  Is this the right room for an argument?

Other Man says  I've told you once.

Man says  No you haven't!

Other Man says  Yes I have.
```

**Error:**
In most cases i end up receiving just a print statement

```
  ---- read all---
```

Comment: Do you ever *call* `read_file`?!

Comment: do you just want to replace `:` with says?

Comment: 1) your indenation is rather wrong... now your `read_file( )` has only one line; 2) read about `str.partition()` 3) close the file after read - even better use `with open(filename) as f: ...` construction

Comment: ...is not in the code you've posted. Files work like reading from tape - you have to rewind (`seek(0)`) once you've reached the end. I suggest you restructure your code - amongst other things, there is too much code in the `try` block and you're using a [bare `except`](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/).

Comment: As side note, I'd recommend using [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for filenames i.e. `r'C:\Users\Adam\Documents\eBook\PythonData\sketch1.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some code missing in your example. For example, I don't understand why you can loop over data without it having been defined in the scope of the for loop (it's only defined inside the read_file function, which is never called). Also, the code is unnecessarily complicated, so unless there's any specific way of doing it with split, I'd do as follows:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\eBook\\PythonData\\sketch1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.replace(':', ' says', 1)
```

This will also close the file after you have finished reading it (due to the with statement).

Comment: Thanks, I like the use of using with. However sketch.txt has scenarios where few lines doesn't have ':' and few has many ':' so i always want to look for ':' and split at first one.

Comment: This example should work then as well. The third argument, 1, to str.replace() will only replace the first occurrence of : in the line, and if none is found, the string will be returned as it was.